# Removing the access to a column from a model method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on rails 2.3.11. 
I have a model with blog( id,title,description, referred_publications)
referred_publications is not a mandatory field.

In my app_Config by default i am keeping referred_publications as false.

I have included the condition of checking whether it is enabled/disabled in the config in the VIEWS for submitting the blog.

FOr instance if someone is doing from somewhere and not from my UI/

From my Model side ,

I would like to do if referred_publications is enabled from config , then the instance can be saved , But if not enabled , and only if the user is trying to use the attribute referred_publications then to throws error or if he is not    using that referred_publications , then it can save without error

But how to do the above from the MODEL side.

Please give suggestions in resolving this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a custom validation.

If you have a `Blog` model which conditionally requires the presence of an attribute, each time a `Blog` is saved it needs to check if the attribute is required right now, and if so validate its presence. Like so:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :referred_publications_present_if_required?

    private

    def referred_publications_present_if_required?
        if AppConfig.require_referred_publications
            errors.add(:referred_publications, "must be present")
        end
    end
end
```

See [Rails Guides: Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods) for more info. It also might be wise to encapsulate the check to see if the attribute is required into a method on the model, which both your views and this method above can use, instead of putting the check to AppConfig in both places.

Hope this helps!